# Geocoder ".near" not working with mongoId

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, google-maps, mongoid, rails-geocoder

I am using [Geocoder](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/) gem for finding near location and locate it in google maps.

**Posting Model**

```
class Posting
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Geocoder::Model::Mongoid


  field :id
  field :title
  field :coordinates, :type => Array
  field :address

  after_validation :reverse_geocode_address


  index({ location: "2dsphere" }, { min: -200, max: 200 })

  belongs_to :user

  def reverse_geocode_address
    self.coordinates = Geocoder.coordinates(self.address)
  end
end
```

When I query

```
Posting.near("chennai",20)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)
.../ruby-2.0.0-preview2/gems/origin-2.1.1/lib/origin/selectable.rb:334:in `near'
```

I can understand , its invoking "near" function in "selectable.rb" (mongoid's) and not the scope of Geocoder.

What I am doing wrong here? How to get results using geocoder.

I am using below versions

MongoDB : db version v2.6.3

MongoID : mongoid (4.0.0)

GEOCoder: geocoder (1.2.6)

Comment: I think you are missing the `geocoded_by :address` or  `reverse_geocoded_by :coordinates`, try adding one of them and see if it worked

Comment: @artmees I am already using it with custom function. As for as I found it seems to be bug in MongoID. It was already is issue list and open. But want to know if there is hacks to make it work , thats why keeping question open.

Comment: could you put a reference to the bug (cause I'm using geocoder and mongoid) ?

Comment: @artmees : https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/issues/98 , this is the same case of mine.

Comment: @artmees : on last line , "It appears that the .near method from geocoder is being replaced by the standard Mongoid method." i hope it also happens in my case.

Comment: try using this http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html#geo_near , might help cause this issue is weird ?! (specially that it's open from long time ago)

Comment: @artmees : Actually I used geo_near , but I am not sure about geo_near_distance unit (It returns 1.8 , 1.6 ) , If I query with :unit => "km" , its breaking with undefined option unit.

Comment: @artmees : Can you help me with last comment. thanks in advance.

Comment: I wish I could, I've never used (or actually knew of) the unit option :D

Comment: @artmees  : Oh , no issues. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem than you.
Droped that gem to make it directly with mongoid.

```
class Localizable

  include Mongoid::Document

  field :coordinates,           type: Array,  default: nil
  index({ coordinates: "2d" },  { min: -180, max: 180 })

  validates_presence_of :coordinates

  ## returns localizables matching params
  #
  # @param la [Float] latitude
  # @param lo [Float] longitude
  # @param ra [Float] range in km
  # @return [Mongoid]
  def self.at_range(la, lo, ra)
    geo_near([la, lo]).max_distance(ra.fdiv(111.12))
  end

  def latitude
    coordinates[0]
  end

  def longitude
    coordinates[1]
  end
end
```

`Localizable.at_range(48, 2, 10) 
=> []`